# changing/removing hotkey for annotate in industry compatible keymap?

Tags: shortcut

I'm using industry compatible mode, but I can't find the annotate draw section in keymap option to change it. It's set to  <kbd>D</kbd> key by default, but I don't think I will use annotate often and don't want to use  <kbd>D</kbd> key for it.

I want to set it to Origin (kinda like in Maya, you can use  <kbd>D</kbd> key to change pivot).

I can see it when I set keymap preset to Blender setting, but not in industry compatible mode.

I tried assign the function I want to use with assign shortcut, but since  <kbd>D</kbd> key is already used for annotate, it doesn't work and didn't overwrite it.